# Bar code not being read

Tags: c#

I am creating a software that generates some barcodes in a pdf file. The code I am using to generate the barcodes is given below. The return of the method I set to my "imagBarcode.Src", that is an image tag running in the codebehind. For some reason, the barcodes generated are not being read by any barcode reader. Can someone give me some help to understand what's going on with my code. Thanks in advance.

```
  public string GenerateBarCode(string code)
    {

        BarcodeInter25 code25 = new BarcodeInter25();
        code25.ChecksumText = true;
        code25.Code = code;

        byte[] barCodeResult;

        System.Drawing.Image bc = code25.CreateDrawingImage(System.Drawing.Color.Black, System.Drawing.Color.White);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bc.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            barCodeResult = ms.ToArray();
        }

        var barCode = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(barCodeResult);

        return barCode;
    }
```

Comment: Can you find a code 25 barcode that does scan, generate the same barcode using your program, and visually compare them?

Comment: Also, are you printing these PDFs? Some readers won't scan computer screens.